# DateTime Format yyyymm

Tags: c#, linq

I've found every DateTime format you can think of except the one I need: yyyymm.  How do I go about getting this?

I have the following code I'm working with:

```
List <string> routines = new List<string>();
routines.Add("1 - Routine");
routines.Add("6 - Planned Outage");

int year = 2011;
int quarter = 1;

DateTime timeframe = new DateTime(year, (quarter * 3), 01).AddMonths(1); 

var results =

    (from wo in WORKORDERs

        join wot in WORKORDERTYPEs on wo.Wot_oi equals wot.Wotyoi

        join pri in PRIORITies on wo.Prio_oi equals pri.Priooi

        join s in SITEs on wo.BEparn_oi equals s.Siteoi

    where wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= year - 3 && wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= 2006
        && wo.Audt_created_dttm < timeframe && (s.Id =="NM" || s.Id == "TH") && 
        !wot.Id.Contains("stand") &&  !(wo.Ci_cnc_date != null && pri.Prioid != "1 - Routine" &&
        pri.Prioid != "6 - Planned Outage") && (SqlMethods.Like(pri.Prioid, "1%") || 
        SqlMethods.Like(pri.Prioid, "2%") || SqlMethods.Like(pri.Prioid, "3%"))     

    select new {PM = wo.Wosource, Site = s.Id, Priority = pri.Prioid, Worktype = wot.Id,
        WoNumber = wo.Id, Description = wo.Aenm, CreateDate = wo.Audt_created_dttm,
        CloseDate = wo.Clsdt_date,
        MonthNum = String.Format("{0:yyyy mm}",  wo.Clsdt_date), 
        Planning = routines.Contains(pri.Prioid) ? "Planned" : "Unplanned"});
```

I tried using:

```
MonthNum = String.Format("{0:yyyy mm}",  wo.Clsdt_date)
```

and that gives me the year correctly but the months are all 00.  I'm guessing this is because the format for wo.Clsdt_date is different than my string format (it's mm/dd/yyyy).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `MM`, not `mm`. `mm` is minutes.

Comment: @ Rawling: Well that's embarrassing.  Duh.  I can't believe I didn't see that!  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Easy mistake to make, especially if you're a Programming Newbie :p

Comment: @ Rawling:  That's me!  I recently started my first programming internship and have been feeling like a first grader in med school.  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

"mm" is for minutes, "MM" is for Month, but with 2 digits of month.  So in June 2012 you will have 201206, however if you need only one digit for month, you can use one "M" instead "yyyyM" and you will get 20126

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM")
```

Answer (score 1):

In date formatting, `mm` means minutes, not months. Use `MM` instead.

Comment: @ Adam V:  Thanks for the help.  Please excuse the brain fart.  I don't know why I couldn't see that.